# Merge Two Array of Object based on its Index (Without Key) Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have a problem that make me stuck for a while. I am using **Javascript**.
I have two arrays of object that look like this:

**1st Array:**

> [
> {
> color: "Red",
> material: "carbon"
> },
> {
> color: "Black",
> material: "iron"
> }
> ]

**2nd Array**

> [
> [
> {
> year_released: 2000
> },
> {
> price: 3000
> },
> {
> year_built: 1998
> }
> ],
> [
> {
> year_released: 1996
> },
> {
> price: 5000
> },
> {
> year_built: 1990
> }
> ]
> ]

**I need to merge those arrays of object to become like this:**

> [
> {
> color: "Red",
> material: "carbon",
> year_released: 2000,
> price: 3000,
> year_built: 1998
> },
> {
> color: "Black",
> material: "iron",
> year_released: 1996,
> price: 5000,
> year_built: 1990
> }
> ]

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: In your expected output, where is the input for `{ color: "Black", material: "iron", year_released: 1996, price: 5000, year_built: 1990 }` coming from? And for that matter, `spoiler` is a `spoiler` in the first array and a `material` in the output?
I think you'll clear up your data first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Object.assign()` to merge the objects and iterate through the target and source object arrays as *per* your requirements.

```js
const targets = [ { color: "Red", spoiler: "carbon" }, { color: "Blue", spoiler: "oxygen" } ];
const sources = [ [ { year_released: 2000 }, { price: 3000 }, { year_built: 1998 } ], [ { year_released: 1996 }, { price: 5000 }, { year_built: 1990  } ] ];

const returnedTargets = targets.map((target, i) => 
  Object.assign({}, target, ...sources[i])
);

console.log(returnedTargets);

// console.log(target, sources, returnedTargets);
// [{"color":"Red","spoiler":"carbon"},{"color":"Blue","spoiler":"oxygen"}]
// [[{"year_released":2000},{"price":3000},{"year_built":1998}],[{"year_released":1996},{"price":5000},{"year_built":1990}]]
// [{"color":"Red","spoiler":"carbon","year_released":2000,"price":3000,"year_built":1998},{"color":"Blue","spoiler":"oxygen","year_released":1996,"price":5000,"year_built":1990}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operators:

```js
const arr1 = [{ color: "Red", spoiler: "carbon" }];
const arr2 = [[ { year_released: 2000 }, { price: 3000 }, { year_built: 1998 } ]];
console.log({ ...Object.assign({}, ...arr1), ...Object.assign({}, ...arr2[0]) });
```